# c# split txt file in readalllines

Tags: c#, sql

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

   var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
   //file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
   string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file.FileName);
   .
   .
   .

      //}
   return View("~/~/xxxDB/xxxxx");
}
```

Input TXT FILE:

```
LINE1: CLASS ABC 1 1 2 
LINE2: NAMES
LINE3: INFO 0 0 0 0 
LINE4: KEY *NULL*
LINE5: BCMD *NULL*
LINE6: RCMD *NULL*
```

column name:

```
class_a
class_b
class_c
class_d
names_a
info_a
info_b
info_c
info_d
.
.
.
```

I decided to write a coding logic is if then statement, if the lines is like class and then put the value into the datatable and split down by " ". How can  i do it, please help.

Comment: Use a Foreach ( var line in lines ) to loop around your lines, then split again by a space var split = line.split(" "); - then you can switch ( split[0] ) case "INFO": case "KEY": case "BCMD" etc etc.

Comment: Does the txt file really start with `LINE1`...`LINE2`... ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes

Answer (score 0):

Use StreamReader to read txt line by line

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new   StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
string line;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FileName);
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(' ');
    string classA = fields[0];
    string classB = fields[1];
    // and so on
}

sr.Close();
```

This loops through the contents of the file a line at a time rather than the "slurping" of the file that `ReadAllLines` would do.